# List count gives null after adding elements

Tags: c#, sharppcap, packet.net

I am having trouble retrieving values from the list
Packet.net and SharpPcap are the two libraries used here !
I have 2 function which does the main work
1st one
This function is called from `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ProcessPacket), ph);`
which is inside a background worker
This is the function which calls the ProcessTcpPacket()

```
private void ProcessPacket(object p)
    {
        PacketHolder pHolder = (PacketHolder) p;
        RawCapture raw = pHolder.RawPacket;

        Packet packet = null;
        if (raw.LinkLayerType == LinkLayers.Ethernet)
        {
            packet = Packet.ParsePacket(PacketDotNet.LinkLayers.Ethernet, raw.Data);
        }
        else if (raw.LinkLayerType == LinkLayers.LinuxSLL)
        {
            packet = Packet.ParsePacket(PacketDotNet.LinkLayers.LinuxSLL, raw.Data);
        }

        while (packet.PayloadPacket != null)
        {
            packet = packet.PayloadPacket;
        }

        if (packet is TcpPacket && packet.PayloadData != null)
        {
            if (packet.PayloadData.Length > 0)
            {
                TcpPacket tcp = (TcpPacket) packet;
                ProcessTcpPacket(tcp, raw.Timeval, pHolder.Index); //called here!
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (packet.PayloadData.Length > 0)
            {
                UdpPacket udp = (UdpPacket) packet;
                ProcessUdpPacket(udp, raw.Timeval, pHolder.Index);
            }
        }

    }

private void ProcessTcpPacket(TcpPacket tcp, PosixTimeval posixTimeval, ulong Index)
    {
        IpPacket parentPacket = (IpPacket) tcp.ParentPacket;

        IPAddress tcpSrcAddress = SourceIPList.Find(srcIP => srcIP.Equals(parentPacket.SourceAddress));
        IPAddress tcpDstAddress = DestinationIPList.Find(dstIP => dstIP.Equals(parentPacket.DestinationAddress));

        if (tcpSrcAddress.Equals(parentPacket.SourceAddress) || tcpDstAddress.Equals(parentPacket.DestinationAddress))
        {
            PacketDetails pd = new PacketDetails(); //class with simple getters and setters
            pd.Index = Index;
            pd.Time = posixTimeval;
            pd.Buffer = tcp.PayloadData;
            //TcpPackets.Add(pd);
            socketHelper.tcpPackets.Add(pd); //properly adds all the packets to list 

        }
    }
```

Now The below function is inside SocketHelper Class where I want to retrieve the data inside the tcpPackets list

```
public void ProcessTCPMessage(TcpClient tcpClient, NetworkStream stream, byte[] clientByte)
    {
        tcpPackets = new List<PacketDetails>(128);
        strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(clientByte, 0, clientByte.Length);
        myClient = tcpClient;
        strRequest = strRequest.Substring(0, 5);
        _form1 = new Form1();
        if (strRequest.Equals("Hello"))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                strResponse = tcpPackets[i].Buffer.ToString(); // here I get the list count as null and throws an exception..
            }
        }
        else
        {
            strResponse = "What?";
        }
        bytesSent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strResponse);
        stream.Write(bytesSent, 0, bytesSent.Length);
    }
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong ! Plz help ! And Try not to be rude if I am doing some thing silly! Just reply thinking I am noob ! :P :D

Comment: You are assigning a List of PacketDetails (of 128 entries) to  tcpPackets, You never fill it with anything, but do start reading from it (where your error is).

Comment: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. This is the exception I get and Marvin if I do tcpPackets = new List<PacketDetails>(); then also it wont work !
And that is just a default initial capacity that shouldn't cause any problem

Answer (score 0):

`tcpPackets` is empty: it is initialized as a list with an initial capacity of 128 items, but it does not contain any items (there is no code that add items to it), hence trying to access its first 100 items will result in an error.

Comment: When print to console while adding I get the list count of more than 8000, Forgot to say The ProcessPacket(object p) function is in the Form1.cs, only ProcessTCPMessage() is in another class !

Comment: My friend I am adding to `tcpPackets`
[link](http://s15.postimg.org/mf281x117/untitled.jpg)
Check the debug image in the link

Comment: Yes, you are adding items to the `tcpPackets` property of the `socketHelper` object, that has nothing to do with the `tcpPackets` local variable that is causing the exception - that is declared and never added to, nor passed to another function before being accessed

Answer (score 0):

You are instantiating the `tcpPackets` list at the beginning of the `ProcessTCPMessage` method, but you don't put in any elements before using it in the `for` loop. So when you're trying to reed the `Buffer` property of the list element, the element is empty (or more accurately, `null`), resulting in a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: tcpPackets = new List<PacketDetails>(); then also it wont work !

Comment: That doesn't make a difference. At some point, you need to insert some objects into the List. You're just creating an empty one.